# Making a pre-existing neural network modular

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-learning

I am following a tutorial on deep learning from a book and the source code can be found [here](https://github.com/oreilly-japan/deep-learning-from-scratch).

Using `ch07/simple_convnet.py`, I want to make a modular neural network, with functions such as `network.addlayer('relu')`, `network.conv_param = {...})`, etc.

How can I achieve this? Do I have to change the `self.params` section, and the `self.layers` section?

I am new to deep learning so, I would appreciate a clear answer.

Also, is this method not recommended? I googled `modular neural network` but there were barely any to be found.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is really vague, can you please give a clearer explanation of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Axois does the title change help?